# Is the Hartree-Fock approximation getting better and better for higher atoms?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, quantum-chemistry

As the atomic number $Z$ increases, is the Hartree-Fock approximation getting better and better, or worse and worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hartree-Fock is less accurate for heavier atoms. There are more configurations and these are closer in energy to each other, so multiconfigurational Hartree-Fock (MCHF) is required. Relativistic effects become more important so the Dirac equation must be solved, in case you are referring to Schrödinger based Hartree-Fock.

Dirac MCHF code can be found [here](https://nlte.nist.gov/MCHF/) and a database of atomic spectra is [here](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database).